# Conveyor belt object fall through problem

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision, graph-editor

I watched a [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHUqM4ny8RA) and tried to learn how to make a conveyor belt. Everything went well until I put a cube on the belt. Somehow, the cube just fell through the belt. I googled a lot even watched other tutorial videos but still got the same result.

Here are the images of my object rigid body settings:

1. the cube setting
   [image]
2. the conveyor belt setting
   [image]

Any advise as to what I'm missing or doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_TPJ4rOOEeRb3iB-llQ-H6oA_8FO4tRz/view)

Comment: Hi and welcome. :) Please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/197334/edit) your question and add images that show your scene settings, and help to illustrate your question *visually*. Currently your question relies on external links, which is not as helpful to those who would answer your question. Please use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for blend files in the future as well, and see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help) for more on how the site works. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Timaroberts I am working on re-editing my question. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Timaroberts , can you see the photos? I successfully uploaded them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your margin settings that are causing this problem. Increase it until you get it right.[image]